# Diamond Operator Compiles under OpenJDK but not SunJDK 7

Tags: playframework-1.x, java

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate, I've searched and found some with related issues but not about the differences in Java.

```
private List<Stuff> apps = new ArrayList<Stuff>();
// compiles under both


private List<Stuff> apps = new ArrayList<>();
// compiles under OpenJDK 7
// SunJDK 7 Error raised is : Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token
```

Any ideas why this is the case? I like to use OpenJDK on my *nix servers and dev boxes but sometimes I use someone else's Windows laptop for dev and testing and this is the first time I've had a problem between the two versions. Would appreciate any advice or thoughts!

Also I use Netbeans 7.2 (which does not flag an error on Windows or Debain). The program uses the Play Framework 1.2.5 and has the java source set to 1.7.

```
javac -version
javac 1.7.0_01
```

and

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_01"
Java<TM> SE Runtime-Environment <build 1.7.0_01-b08>
```

and checked Netbeans everywhere I could an source is 1.7 everywhere I can tell. Compiling via the command line produced the same error described above.

ANSWER?

I updated to the latest version of SunJDK/Java (1.7.0_13) and the issue resolved for me.

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you using Eclipse? Make sure it hasn't done its magic tricks of changing the Java libaries in Project/Build settings, or changing the "compile to" version to 5. Mine has an annoying habit of doing those things by itself quite frequently!

Comment: Agree with Mr Spoon. Works on my machine. If you use maven, make sure the build section has the targetVersion set properly: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Sorry, I use Netbeans, which also has the habit of annoying switching back to source 1.5 instead of 1.7 on Windows, never does so on Debian. I amended my answer to say Netbeans, if that matters.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `javac -version` and `java -version`, as well as the compiler settings in your IDE. Even when using Java 1.7, you can force it to compile in 1.6 mode by including `-source 1.6`. So if your IDE adds this setting to your build, it will fail with Java 1.7
Oh, and **try compiling on command line** to see whether it is a Java or a Netbeans issue!

Comment: Thanks. I added the requested information.

Comment: Compiled fine for me using SunJDK 1.7.0_03.

Comment: Works for me in NB 7.2 and JDK 1.7.0_11

Comment: I was just able to reinstall jdk and now under jdk 1.7.0_13 the error is gone and everything compiles fine under NB 7.2 and JDK1.7.0_13. Perhaps a bug in the early version or a bad install. Thanks for the help and sorry I wasn't able to reinstall sooner.

Comment: what's the protocol on answering to this one? anyone want to throw up an "update to the latest version" :-)

Comment: @bladmiral - please post your finding as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to the latest version of SunJDK/Java (1.7.0_13) and the issue resolved.